# How to make a report in crystal report that its columns' number may changes anytime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am working on a report in crystal-report which its columns are the days of month
and as you know the number of the days changes every month.

***So my question is how to change the number of columns from 30 to 29
for example automatically***

can you help by sending video tutorial about this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added clarifications to my question already

Answer (score 0):

One option is to insert a CrossTab  and set the column to be the day of the month.
The CrossTab would adapt the number of columns to the data automatically.

But the question is not clear. I'm just guessing that would be a useful option.

Comment: I have added clarifications to my question